# Arabic numerals (1, 2, ...) as labels in ```enumerate``` when using polyglossia

Tags: numbering, enumerate, polyglossia

I'm trying to compile an Armenian text that has an enumerated list. Instead of regular numbers like 1, 2, ..., I get the Armenian letters as enumeration labels. Below is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily{\armenianfont}{DejaVu Serif}
\setdefaultlanguage{armenian}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Հայերեն տեքստ 1 (a text in Armenian 1)
    \item Հայերեն տեքստ 2 (a text in Armenian 2)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This is the output :

[image]

I'd like to have regular arabic numbers 1, 2, *etc.* on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add option `numerals=arabic` to `\setdefaultlanguage` command

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily{\armenianfont}{DejaVu Serif}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=arabic]{armenian}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Հայերեն տեքստ 1 (a text in Armenian 1)
    \item Հայերեն տեքստ 2 (a text in Armenian 2)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that worked for me is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily{\armenianfont}{DejaVu Serif}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{armenian}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \begin{armenian}
    \item  Հայերեն տեքստ 1 (a text in Armenian 1)
    \item Հայերեն տեքստ 2 (a text in Armenian 2)
     \end{armenian}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```